# How to Look for a binary sequence in a file

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, binary, compression, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [byte[] array pattern search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/byte-array-pattern-search)

I am trying to write a simple compression algorthm in C# and .NET 3.5 and I need to be able to search a particular file for occurrences of a certain sequence of bits. what is the fastest way of doing this?

Comment: This question asks to look in a file not a byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file is 8K I would start by reading all the bytes into an in memory array like this:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

There is a code sample to search in this stack overflow entry:

[byte[] array pattern search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/byte-array-pattern-search)

Comment: I'm not looking for text in a binary file. Rather, I'm looking for a sequence of bits in a file. If it matters, the file will be 8 kilobytes in size.

Comment: How large of a sequence of bits?

Comment: I might have been unclear: i am searching within an 8KB file for up to 128 bytes at a time it looks like.

Comment: Was the new stack overflow link I provided helpful?

Comment: Sort of. I'm looking for the simplest way to do so, not the fastest way.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020438/c-array-subset-fetching for a better description of what i need.

Comment: The function in that link is pretty darn simple, is it too slow for you?