# C# Array Subset fetching

Tags: c#, algorithm, arrays, search

I have an array of bytes and i want to determine if the contents of this array of bytes exists within another larger array as a continuous sequence. What is the simplest way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naive approach is:

```
public static bool IsSubsetOf(byte[] set, byte[] subset) {
    for(int i = 0; i < set.Length && i + subset.Length <= set.Length; ++i)
        if (set.Skip(i).Take(subset.Length).SequenceEqual(subset))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

For more efficient approaches, you might consider more advanced string matching algorithms like [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_algorithm).

Comment: @Michal: It's O(n*m) which might be considered inefficient, but if you're worrying about Skip and Take, don't. This is as efficient as a couple for loops. As I said, if performance is an issue, you should consider a more advanced algorithm.

Comment: @Mehrdad - yeah, but m*n can get quite big for binary data... I know that Skip() and Take() is done by deferred execution - so it's just n component of O(m*n) coming from SequenceEquals...

Comment: Performance will be a problem but for now i just want to get my code working. this ought to do nicely...

Comment: `Skip()` can't actually do an indexed jump.  It must call `MoveNext()` on the iterator `i` times.  See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/26/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-40-optimization.aspx for why.  But with the "if you are worried about perf... do something else" caveat, this answer is sound.

Answer (score 3):

Try to adapt some string search algorithm. One of the fastest is [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm) . It's quite easy as well. For binary data, [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm might work very efficiently as well.

Answer (score 0):

This, which is a 1/1 port of this answer: [Searching for a sequence of Bytes in a Binary File with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507780/searching-for-a-sequence-of-bytes-in-a-binary-file-with-java)

Is a very efficient way of doing so:

```
public static class KmpSearch {

    public static int IndexOf(byte[] data, byte[] pattern) {
        int[] failure = ComputeFailure(pattern);

        int j = 0;
        if (data.Length == 0) return -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
            while (j > 0 && pattern[j] != data[i]) {
                j = failure[j - 1];
            }
            if (pattern[j] == data[i]) { j++; }
            if (j == pattern.Length) {
                return i - pattern.Length + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }


    private static int[] ComputeFailure(byte[] pattern) {
        int[] failure = new int[pattern.Length];

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < pattern.Length; i++) {
            while (j > 0 && pattern[j] != pattern[i]) {
                j = failure[j - 1];
            }
            if (pattern[j] == pattern[i]) {
                j++;
            }
            failure[i] = j;
        }

        return failure;
    }
}
```