# Searching for a sequence of Bytes in a Binary File with Java

Tags: java, search, byte, binaryfiles

I have a sequence of bytes that I have to search for in a set of Binary files using Java.

Example: I'm searching for the byte sequence `DEADBEEF` (in hex) in a Binary file.
How would I go about doing this in Java? Is there a built-in method, like `String.contains()` for Binary files?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

No, there is no built-in method to do that. But, directly copied from [HERE](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t129673-search-byte-for-pattern.html) (with two fixes applied to the original code):

```
/**
 * Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm for Pattern Matching
 */
class KMPMatch {
    /**
     * Finds the first occurrence of the pattern in the text.
     */
    public static int indexOf(byte[] data, byte[] pattern) {
        if (data.length == 0) return -1;

        int[] failure = computeFailure(pattern);    
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            while (j > 0 && pattern[j] != data[i]) {
                j = failure[j - 1];
            }
            if (pattern[j] == data[i]) { j++; }
            if (j == pattern.length) {
                return i - pattern.length + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Computes the failure function using a boot-strapping process,
     * where the pattern is matched against itself.
     */
    private static int[] computeFailure(byte[] pattern) {
        int[] failure = new int[pattern.length];

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < pattern.length; i++) {
            while (j > 0 && pattern[j] != pattern[i]) {
                j = failure[j - 1];
            }
            if (pattern[j] == pattern[i]) {
                j++;
            }
            failure[i] = j;
        }

        return failure;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very little optimization: you don't need to compute the failure function of the pattern if the data.length is zero ==> you can move the data.length zero checking to the first line of the function.

Answer (score 4):

```
private int bytesIndexOf(byte[] source, byte[] search, int fromIndex) {
    boolean find = false;
    int i;
    for (i = fromIndex; i < (source.length - search.length); i++) {
        if (source[i] == search[0]) {
            find = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < search.length; j++) {
                if (source[i + j] != search[j]) {
                    find = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (find) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!find) {
        return -1;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: '<Source.length-Search.length'
should be '<=' instead

Answer (score 3):

You can find sequence of bytes from giga-bytes order file using bigdoc.

Lib and Example here on Github at: https://github.com/riversun/bigdoc

```
package org.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.riversun.bigdoc.bin.BigFileSearcher;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        byte[] searchBytes = "hello world.".getBytes("UTF-8");

        File file = new File("/var/tmp/yourBigfile.bin");

        BigFileSearcher searcher = new BigFileSearcher();

        List<Long> findList = searcher.searchBigFile(file, searchBytes);

        System.out.println("positions = " + findList);
    }
}
```

If you want to search it on memory,check this.
Examples here on Github at: https://github.com/riversun/finbin

```
 import java.util.List;

 import org.riversun.finbin.BigBinarySearcher;

 public class Example {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

         BigBinarySearcher bbs = new BigBinarySearcher();

         byte[] iamBigSrcBytes = "Hello world.It's a small world.".getBytes("utf-8");

         byte[] searchBytes = "world".getBytes("utf-8");

         List<Integer> indexList = bbs.searchBytes(iamBigSrcBytes, searchBytes);

         System.out.println("indexList=" + indexList);
     }
 }
```

Returns all the matched positions in the array of bytes

It also can withstand a large array of bytes:)

Answer (score 1):

For those who prefer libraries, there is an implementation (source below) of the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm in Twitter's Elephant-Bird open source library (Apache license).

You can find the library on Github at: https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird

```
package com.twitter.elephantbird.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * An efficient stream searching class based on the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm.
 * For more on the algorithm works see: http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/kmpen.htm.
 */
public class StreamSearcher {

  protected byte[] pattern_;
  protected int[] borders_;

  // An upper bound on pattern length for searching. Throws exception on longer patterns
  public static final int MAX_PATTERN_LENGTH = 1024;

  public StreamSearcher(byte[] pattern) {
    setPattern(pattern);
  }

  /**
   * Sets a new pattern for this StreamSearcher to use.
   * @param pattern
   *          the pattern the StreamSearcher will look for in future calls to search(...)
   */
  public void setPattern(byte[] pattern) {
    if (pattern.length > MAX_PATTERN_LENGTH) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The maximum pattern length is " + MAX_PATTERN_LENGTH);
    }

    pattern_ = Arrays.copyOf(pattern, pattern.length);
    borders_ = new int[pattern_.length + 1];
    preProcess();
  }

  /**
   * Searches for the next occurrence of the pattern in the stream, starting from the current stream position. Note
   * that the position of the stream is changed. If a match is found, the stream points to the end of the match -- i.e. the
   * byte AFTER the pattern. Else, the stream is entirely consumed. The latter is because InputStream semantics make it difficult to have
   * another reasonable default, i.e. leave the stream unchanged.
   *
   * @return bytes consumed if found, -1 otherwise.
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public long search(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    long bytesRead = 0;

    int b;
    int j = 0;

    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
      bytesRead++;

      while (j >= 0 && (byte)b != pattern_[j]) {
        j = borders_[j];
      }
      // Move to the next character in the pattern.
      ++j;

      // If we've matched up to the full pattern length, we found it.  Return,
      // which will automatically save our position in the InputStream at the point immediately
      // following the pattern match.
      if (j == pattern_.length) {
        return bytesRead;
      }
    }

    // No dice, Note that the stream is now completely consumed.
    return -1;
  }

  /**
   * Builds up a table of longest "borders" for each prefix of the pattern to find. This table is stored internally
   * and aids in implementation of the Knuth-Moore-Pratt string search.
   * <p>
   * For more information, see: http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/kmpen.htm.
   */
  protected void preProcess() {
    int i = 0;
    int j = -1;
    borders_[i] = j;
    while (i < pattern_.length) {
      while (j >= 0 && pattern_[i] != pattern_[j]) {
        j = borders_[j];
      }
      borders_[++i] = ++j;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where to stand the 1024 byte limitation for the pattern as stated by the unused MAX_PATTERN_LENGTH member ?

Answer (score 0):

If the approved answer is too complex for your task then try simple code below. It uses native Java libs only

```
/**
 * Search byte array for the byte pattern
 *
 * @param array to look into
 * @param pattern to search
 * @return index of first occurrence of the pattern, -1 otherwise
 */
public static int searchBytePattern(byte[] array, byte[] pattern) {
    if (pattern.length > array.length) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - pattern.length; i++) {
        if (Arrays.compare(array, i, i + pattern.length, pattern, 0, pattern.length) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```