# Java: How to check if a byte[] array exists in a file?

Tags: java, file

I come up an idea to read a byte[] array with the same size of the input, and check one by one. But it seems not very efficient. Is there a way to solve it by using rolling hash?

Comment: do i get you right, you have an byte-array X and you have a file and you want to check if X is somewhere in the file data?

Comment: Show some code and then ask a specific question

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507780/searching-for-a-sequence-of-bytes-in-a-binary-file-with-java

Comment: You can compute a rolling hash (Rabin Karp or some other ) , over a sliding window of size as byte array, over the entire file and check whether hash is the same. If same , then compare byte by byte. Since computing rolling hash is O(1), you will be able to solve the problem in O(file_size) .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 or above please check the

```
java.util.Optional<T>
```

The documentation is here
[Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)
 If I got what you mean correctly