# Find location of a short sequence of bytes in byte array

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, arrays

How can I efficiently find the location of the first instance of a four byte sequence within a byte array?  Is there something more efficient than looping through the whole array, or a built-in method?

I'm searching through a byte array for a pair of `CrLF`.  I can't convert it to string for an `InStr` first because I need the position of it in the original byte array.

I am trying to figure out the location of this, as it delimits between a string portion and a binary portion, similar (well, exactly like for this part of it) to an HTTP header.  There is a string portion, and two `CrLf` before the content begins.

Comment: You'll need to convert some examples to vb (or just use them in a referenced C# project), but some good alternatives are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/byte-array-pattern-search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)'s algorithm, which is better than linear in the average.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming nothing about the data set (sorted/special ordering) the best you can do is an O(n) algorithm, which means looking through the whole array once.

Comment: Ok, that answers my question.  Thank you!