# Extracting a binary file from other file encoding\conversion mistake

Tags: c#, file, encoding, byte, type-conversion

I have two binary files, `"bigFile.bin"` and `"smallFile.bin"`.
The `"bigFile.bin"` contains `"smallFile.bin"`.
Opening it in beyond compare confirms that.

I want to extract the smaller file form the bigger into a "result.bin" that equals `"smallFile.bin"`.
I have two keywords- one for the start position ("Section") and one for the end position ("Man");

I tried the following:

```
   byte[] bigFile = File.ReadAllBytes("bigFile.bin");
   UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
   string text =  enc.GetString(bigFile);

   int startIndex = text.IndexOf("Section");
   int endIndex = text.IndexOf("Man");

   string smallFile = text.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);

   File.WriteAllBytes("result.bin",enc.GetBytes(smallFile));
```

I tried to compare the result file with the origin small file in beyond compare, which shows hex representation comparison.
nost of the bytes areequal -but some not.

For example in the new file I have `84` but in the old file I have `EF BF BD` sequence instead.

What can cause those differences? Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working with binary files, you should not use text-related functionality (which includes encodings etc). Work with byte-related methods instead.

Your current code could be converted to work by making it into something like this:

```
   byte[] bigFile = File.ReadAllBytes("bigFile.bin");

   int startIndex = /* assume we somehow know this */
   int endIndex = /* assume we somehow know this */

   var length = endIndex - startIndex;
   var smallFile = new byte[length];
   Array.Copy(bigFile, startIndex, smallFile, 0, length);
   File.WriteAllBytes("result.bin", smallFile);
```

To find `startIndex` and `endIndex` you could even use your previous technique, but something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/byte-array-pattern-search) would be more appropriate.

However this would still be problematic because:

1. Stuffing both binary data and "text" into the same file is going to complicate matters
2. There is still *a lot* of unnecessary copying going on here; you should work with your input as a `Stream` rather than an array of bytes
3. Even worse than the unnecessary copying, any non-stream solution would either need to load all of your input file in memory as happens above (wasteful), or be *exceedingly* complicated to code

So, what to do?

1. Don't read file contents in memory as byte arrays. Work with [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) instead.
2. Wrap a `StreamReader` around the `FileStream` and use it to find the markers for the start and end indexes. Even better, change your file format so that you don't need to search for text.
3. After you know `startIndex` and `length`, use stream functions to seek to the relevant part of your input stream and copy `length` bytes to the output stream.