# Editing hex in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I searched a lot but did not got the clear answer the one I'm looking for.

I want to edit the hex of the file and insert bytes in a `.dll` file

For example

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ("C:\test.dll")

End Sub
```

so that when I click `button1` it searches hex like 1`2 23 34 45 56 67 78`
and modify it to `00 00 00 00 00 00 00`/

Next, I want to insert without overwriting like `12 23 34 45 56`,
and I can insert `12 23 00 00 34 45 56`.

Can anybody can help with these two points?

Thanks.

Comment: 'Patching' a DLL is one thing, adding bytes is likely to break it completely.

Comment: how about Adding in .exe ,will it break ?

Comment: Yes, the same rules apply.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not too large, the simplest approach would be to

1. load the file into a byte array (`File.ReadAllBytes`),
2. [find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/283456/87698) and replace the parts you want to replace,
3. save the file back (`File.WriteAllBytes`).

For inserting, converting the byte array into a `List(Of Byte)`, inserting the bytes and converting it back to an array is probably the easiest solution. (Again, if the file is not too large and the operation is not performance-critical.)

The implementation is left as an exercise.

Comment: As noted above, you cannot insert instructions or data into a DLL, as it would offset every relative branch and jumps that follow. You can however patch it, as long as the resulting machine code is still valid.

Comment: @Heinzi  Could You Please Write Whole Code Like Dim a as string like this taking example as file is in C:\Test.dll ?

Comment: @Drunken Code Monkey how about Adding in .exe ,will it break ?

Comment: @Js78955: Sorry, StackOverflow, is not a "we write your code for you" service. You are a software developer, are you not? Read the documentation, learn the language, try to write the code yourself, and if you have a *specific* question during development, return here and ask a (new) question. :-)

Comment: @Heinzi Im beginner i just started learning vb.net 5-7 days ago where ever i find vb tutorial i check it cus i want to learn vb.net i got interested in it so this basic commands should be known so that if you write it i will implement different way and find new way :)

Comment: i tried im not getting what the link all is in C# and im in vb.net help be bro, i need push to start now im left with nowwhere :( i want to edit the pattern and they totally over my head im not pro im just starter going over my head