# How to check whether a particular string is present in a byte array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

```
    var PDF = new ActionAsPdf("TestReport", null)
    {
            FileName = "TestFile.pdf",
            PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
            PageMargins = { Left = 1, Right = 1 }
    };
    byte[] PDFData = PDF.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);
```

Is it possible to check for a string (eg. "Daily Task") in the 'PDFData' ?
Please guide me. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/byte-array-pattern-search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert `byte` array into `string`:

```
var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(PDFData);
var isContains = str.Contains("Daily Task");
```

An example:

```
string dailyTask = " Daily Task ";
byte[] PDFData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dailyTask);
var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(PDFData);
var isContains = str.Contains("Daily Task");
Console.WriteLine(isContains);
```

Comment: example works as expected. Is it possible to scan the text which is printed on the pdf? This is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @DevSa Does your `PdfData` contain text printed in pdf? If yes, does the above code find your desired    string?

Comment: Nop. I cant find any text from the generated pdf in pdfData.

Comment: According to my question in the title your answer is correct.

Comment: @DEvsa it looks like text of pdf file is stored differently and we cannot find the desired string or encryption is different. You can unmark my reply. It is ok. Maybe you need to create another question "How to find string in generated array by rotativa"?