# How do I find a string in byte array in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have an array of bytes that contains data. I would like to search for a specific string in the array of bytes. I dont know really how to do this in C#

```
byte[] ByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:/MyDoc.docx");

String searchString = "Graphics";
```

How do I find the the word "Graphics" in the array dataArray? Thanks

Comment: If you can have your searchString as byte array as well, this post should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/byte-array-pattern-search

Comment: This won’t work. DOCX files are zipped XML files. So you first need to unzip it in order to get to the text data.

Comment: [There is an SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-document-part) for working with MS Office documents, including search.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your array of bytes into string like here

`string converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`

and after that use the `string.IndexOf()` or `string.Contains()` method

Comment: This has the obvious limitation that you are assuming that you know what sort of string encoding is used in the file.   Other than that, this is a correct anwer to the OP’s question.   However, see the comments on the question for reasons why this isn’t going to work at all in the case of DOCX.

Answer (score 1):

Docx files are **zipped**. The only strings you'll find there are relative to zip headers. There won't be **any** text from your document.

You can see this in Windows by changing the `docx` file extension to `zip` and then double-clicking the file. You'll find an archive with some `XML` content, which can open with any Xml reader, or even notepad.

You could do the same thing manually in code (ie via `System.IO.Compression` types), but you don't have to. There are other libraries that have already done much of the hard work for you to extract the archive and already know what files and schema to look for. Some of them freely available on NuGet.