# Detect an Element in an array and create a new array based on that element

Tags: java, arrays, serial-port, communication

I have a serial communication protocol and I am receiving messages all the time and the messages arrive in an array almost all at the same time and I would like to separate this array into several others using the characters that determine the beginning [ 102] [102] and stopping at the characters that indicate the end of the message [50] [101], how could you do this?

[image]

I tried as follows:

```
byte[] buffer = Arrays.copyOfRange(dados,0,16);
                    byte[] buffer1 =  Arrays.copyOfRange(dados,16,32);
                    byte[] buffer2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(dados, 32, 48);
```

however, if I stop receiving the message from any of my equipment, the main array changes, generating an exception

Comment: What have you tried to do? You have to provide a  [mre] so we can help you solve any errors or fix any incorrect behaviour in your code. Stack Overflow is not meant to be used as a software development service where other people write your code for you.

Comment: I'm sorry I will edit the question with the code snippet of how I did it

Answer (score 0):

- Get the beginning and end positions of your frames. You can use this article to get it. [byte[] array pattern search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/byte-array-pattern-search)
- implement for this something like this:

```
List<Integer> startPositions = getPositions(inputBytes, startPattern);
List<Integer> endPositions = getPositions(inputBytes, endPattern);
```

- Then slice inputBytes by iterating over the starts.
- When you are working on a starts => search the next visible end in your end list.
- Then you can cut the slices